# Reset form without losing submitSucceeded

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

When using React Final Form, is there a way to reset the form without losing the submitSucceeded state. I want to display a success message on the form but I also want to clear it after a successful submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reset()` clears all state. You could either:

a) Notice when `submitSucceeded` becomes `true` and save that state locally with `setState()`, or

b) Clear each field manually, with something like:

```
form.batch(() => {
  form.change('firstField', '')
  form.change('secondField', '')
  form.change('thirdField', '')
  // ...
})
```

Neither is incredibly elegant, but...

Comment: Thanks. I'd done b already. I'm going to send you a PR to add clear to the API. Maybe you'll accept it 

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually reset each field you can loop through all form posted values and reset each individually:

```
const submitForm = async (values, form) => {

    // Do something on form submit here

    // Reset form fields, note in a real world scenario
    // this would be inside a success callback
    Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
        form.change(key, undefined);
        form.resetFieldState(key);
    });
};
```